# How to save an UIImage of an UIImageView with the applied rotation transformation and scaling

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to save an image which will be the output image of the operations resizing, rotating using pinch and rotation gestures. If i export the image i cannot save the output image with the scaled size and orientations. I have an image view inside a view to which i had applied the gesture recognizers and added this as a sub view to another view. I use the code below to get the scaled and rotated image but this is not working.

```
- (UIImage*)captureView
{    
    CGRect rect = [self bounds];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.layer renderInContext:context];
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    image = [image rotateAndScaleFromCameraWithMaxSize:angle];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

and use this above method in the presented view to get the image as

```
UIImage *watermark = [draggableImageView captureView];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(watermark) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

but the saved file is as the original file selected before resizing and rotating.
Kindly help me.

Comment: actually the to ratate and scale your image is not the one you posted.

Comment: I had done rotation and scaling using gesture recognizers in a separate method and saving the scaled and rotated image using the above method